# I was unable to setup my Sitecore 10.2 Angular app using latest NPM version 8.6.0 Node 17.8.0

Tags: sitecore-api, npm

While setting up my first headless `Sitecore 10.2` angular app, I was getting errors like `unable to resolve dependency tree`

```
Sitecore version 10.2
NPM version 8.6.0
Node 17.8.0
```

Command that is failing: `jss create test-myapp-angular-app angular`

Sitecore jss version: Sitecore Headless Services Server XP 19.0.0 rev. 00508.zip

Answer (score 1):

The above issue is a `Sitecore` bug, creating a new `Sitecore` angular app fails with the latest NPM version.

The error occurs when using `NPM 7` and above as the peer dependency installation behavior was changed. As a workaround to this, please manually add `--legacy-peer-deps` flag when running `npm install`.

#Set your `JSS` Project Name

```
$JssAngularProjectName = ‘test-myapp-angular-app’
```

#And then run the following

```
cd $JssAngularProjectName
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
node -e "require('./jss-create.js')({name:'$JssAngularProjectName', hostName:'$JssAngularProjectName.dev.local'}, [])"
rm jss-create.js
```

Or else we can simply downgrade the `NPM` version to any `6.x`, and it will work. For me, `6.14.16` worked.

- Node-16.14.2