# Sitecore JSS deploy throws unexpected response from import status service

Tags: sitecore-client, jss, jss-rendering-sdk

I am running into an error while I deploy the JSS application using the command `jss deploy app -c -d`

- Fresh vanilla `Sitecore 10.2 XM`
- `Sitecore Headless Rendering 20.0.2` on top of it
- Node `v18.16.0`
- npm version `95.1`
- jss --version `21.1.7`
- created hello world JSS app using the command `npm init sitecore-jss angular`
- jss application ran successfully in disconnected mode `jss start`
- made JSS user as admin user in CM, Host entry done, binding done
- Ensured the JSS service is running with [https://sc-102-xm-cm.dev.local/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey={E0FD962E-5AD3-4DA3-9971-9B54A1AF1F22}](https://sc-102-xm-cm.dev.local/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey=%7BE0FD962E-5AD3-4DA3-9971-9B54A1AF1F22%7D)
- completed the jss setup
- performed `jss deploy config` and it successfully placed the config files in \include\zzz folder
- `jss deploy app -c -d` command throws the following error.

[image]

It created the items in Sitecore but not deployed the files in a folder and it's throwing the attached error. following is the log trace.

```
     ManagedPoolThread #5 19:42:18 INFO  Job started: JSSImport-jey-jss-app-demo-angular-7:42:18 PM
     ManagedPoolThread #5 19:42:18 INFO  [JSS] - Importing jey-jss-app-demo-angular as sitecore\JssImport
     ManagedPoolThread #5 19:42:18 INFO  Cache created: 'jssImport[filtered items]' (max size: 10MB, running total: 3181MB)
     ManagedPoolThread #5 19:42:18 INFO  [JSS] - Import database is master
     ManagedPoolThread #5 19:42:18 INFO  [JSS] - Import data contains:
        Templates - 31
        Renderings - 28
        Placeholders - 6
        Route Items - 6
        Other Items - 15
        Dictionary Items - 4

     ManagedPoolThread #5 19:42:18 INFO  [JSS] - Import language is en
     ManagedPoolThread #5 19:42:18 INFO  [JSS] - Reloaded all GraphQL 
     schemas.
     ManagedPoolThread #5 19:42:18 INFO  Job ended: JSSImport-jey-jss-app-demo-angular-7:42:18 PM (units processed: )
     ManagedPoolThread #5 19:42:20 INFO  Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index
     ManagedPoolThread #5 19:42:21 INFO  Job ended: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index (units processed: )
```

Any help would be appreciated to sort out this error and deployment.

**Latest log**

```
            10676 08:51:22 WARN  Accessing disabled functionality: Initialize
        10676 08:51:22 INFO  Cache created: 'runtimeSettingsCache' (max size: 25MB, running total: 2821MB)
        10676 08:51:22 INFO  Cache created: 'clientData' (max size: 25MB, running total: 2846MB)
        10676 08:51:22 INFO  Cache created: 'UserProfileCache' (max size: 5MB, running total: 2851MB)
        ManagedPoolThread #0 08:51:22 WARN  Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.Security\Access Denied / sec'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.
                Message: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
        ManagedPoolThread #0 08:51:22 WARN  Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.Security\Access Granted / sec'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.
                Message: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
        ManagedPoolThread #0 08:51:22 WARN  Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.Security\Access Resolved / sec'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.
                Message: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
        ManagedPoolThread #0 08:51:22 WARN  Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.Security\Modify Requests / sec'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.
                Message: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
        ManagedPoolThread #0 08:51:22 WARN  Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.Security\Programmatic Disabling / sec'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.
                Message: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
        ManagedPoolThread #0 08:51:22 WARN  Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.Security\Programmatic Enabling / sec'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.
                Message: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
        ManagedPoolThread #0 08:51:22 WARN  Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.Security\Programmatic User Switch / sec'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.
                Message: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
        ManagedPoolThread #0 08:51:22 WARN  Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.Security\Read Requests / sec'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.
                Message: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
        ManagedPoolThread #0 08:51:22 WARN  Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.Security\Virtual Users Built / sec'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.
                Message: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
        10676 08:51:22 INFO  Cache created: 'ItemCloningRelations' (max size: 50MB, running total: 2901MB)
        10676 08:51:22 WARN  No session Id managers were found to manage the session Id for the current request. Default asp.net session manager will be used.
        10676 08:51:22 INFO  IAssemblyResolver contains 89 assemblies
        ManagedPoolThread #1 08:51:22 INFO  Job started: JSSImport-jey-jss-app-demo-angular-8:51:22 AM
        ManagedPoolThread #2 08:51:23 WARN  Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.Presentation\Context | Site Changed / sec'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.
                Message: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
        ManagedPoolThread #2 08:51:23 WARN  Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.Presentation\Rendering | Controls Rendered / sec'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.
                Message: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
        ManagedPoolThread #2 08:51:23 WARN  Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.Presentation\Rendering | Controls Rendered From Cache / sec'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.
                Message: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
        ManagedPoolThread #2 08:51:23 WARN  Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.Presentation\Rendering | Pages Generated / sec'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.
                Message: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
        ManagedPoolThread #2 08:51:23 WARN  Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.Presentation\Rendering | Renderings Rendered / sec'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.
                Message: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
        ManagedPoolThread #2 08:51:23 WARN  Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.Presentation\Rendering | Sublayouts Rendered / sec'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.
                Message: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
        ManagedPoolThread #2 08:51:23 WARN  Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.Presentation\Rendering | XmlControls Compiled / sec'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.
                Message: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
        ManagedPoolThread #2 08:51:23 WARN  Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.Presentation\Rendering | Xsl Transforms Rendered / sec'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.
                Message: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
        ManagedPoolThread #2 08:51:23 WARN  Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.Presentation\Rendering | Xaml Controls Compiled / sec'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.
                Message: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.

            ManagedPoolThread #1 08:51:34 WARN  The "Media.LowercaseUrls" setting contains an invalid value. The default value is used instead. Invalid value: "". Default value: "False"
```

**After adding IIS users to Performance Log and Monitor Users Group**

```
        ManagedPoolThread #10 10:34:58 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Agents.IndexingStateSwitcher
    ManagedPoolThread #10 10:34:58 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Agents.IndexingStateSwitcher (units processed: )
    ManagedPoolThread #7 10:35:09 INFO  Job started: JSSImport-jey-jss-app-demo-angular-10:35:09 AM
    ManagedPoolThread #7 10:35:09 INFO  [JSS] - Importing jey-jss-app-demo-angular as sitecore\JssImport
    ManagedPoolThread #7 10:35:09 INFO  Cache created: 'jssImport[html]' (max size: 0 bytes, running total: 3061MB)
    ManagedPoolThread #7 10:35:09 INFO  Cache created: 'jssImport[registry]' (max size: 25MB, running total: 3086MB)
    ManagedPoolThread #7 10:35:09 INFO  Cache created: 'jssImport[viewstate]' (max size: 25MB, running total: 3111MB)
    ManagedPoolThread #7 10:35:09 INFO  Cache created: 'jssImport[xsl]' (max size: 50MB, running total: 3161MB)
    ManagedPoolThread #7 10:35:09 INFO  Cache created: 'jssImport[filtered items]' (max size: 10MB, running total: 3171MB)
    ManagedPoolThread #7 10:35:09 INFO  [JSS] - Import database is master
    ManagedPoolThread #7 10:35:09 INFO  [JSS] - Import data contains:
        Templates - 31
        Renderings - 28
        Placeholders - 6
        Route Items - 6
        Other Items - 15
        Dictionary Items - 4

    ManagedPoolThread #7 10:35:09 INFO  [JSS] - Import language is en
    ManagedPoolThread #10 10:35:09 INFO  Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index
    ManagedPoolThread #10 10:35:10 INFO  Job ended: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index (units processed: )
    ManagedPoolThread #7 10:35:10 INFO  [JSS] - Reloaded all GraphQL schemas.
    ManagedPoolThread #7 10:35:10 INFO  Job ended: JSSImport-jey-jss-app-demo-angular-10:35:09 AM (units processed: )
```

Comment: Check log and attach  stack trace as text.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `jss --version 21.1.7` it is for Sitecore 10.3. Sitecore 10.2 is compatible with the below jss versions. Refer to more details [here](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1000576).

1. Sitecore JavaScript Rendering SDK (JSS) `19.x`
2. Sitecore JavaScript Rendering SDK (JSS) `20.x`

Run the command: `npm install @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli@version-number` replace `version-number` with the jss version you need for example `npm install @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli@20.0.2`

To verify the installation worked, type `jss -version` and you will see your version number installed either locally or globally depending on how you chose to install the jss module.

Try to uninstall the current version using the following command:

`npm uninstall -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli`

Then install the compatible version:

`npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli@20.0.2`

OR

`npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli@19.0.5`

Check sitecore-jss-cli versions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli?activeTab=versions).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Sumit, I have uninstalled the 21.1.7 and installed 20.0.2 version. I am still getting the same error as attached screenshot in the question. Also i have updated question with latest log trace (I just copied only the WARN due to size limit) i dont see any error in log file other than the WARN.

Comment: Now it has permission issue. You can try out this https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-resolve-sitecore-error-message-access-registry-key-birjesh-verma?trk=pulse-article_more-articles_related-content-card

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/tothecore.sk/2018/06/12/setting-permissions-for-reading-creating-counters-in-sitecore-9/amp/

Comment: I have added the IIS users to the groups. But i don't think that's an actual issue. After adding users deployed the app and updated the log in the question above.

Comment: It could be related to npm, try by deleting node module forlder and run npm install again.

Comment: You can also try to setup it on different location/folder. Also try to downgrade node version to 14. Sometimes node version creates an issue.

Comment: Check this one https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/31519/i-was-unable-to-setup-my-sitecore-10-2-angular-app-using-latest-npm-version-8-6

Comment: Does sitecore has the compatibility version for node and npm any where? i couldn't find in the sitecore documentation portal.

Comment: There is no such documents for compatibility with node.